# Item caching in Scrapy

Tags: python, caching, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm scraping a website that's structured like this:

```
Archive
    Article 1
        Authors
            Author 1
            Author 2
        Title
        Body
        Comments
            Comment 1
            Comment 2
    ...
```

Each of the authors in `Authors` has their own profile page. The problem is that authors write multiple articles, so I end up scraping the same authors' profiles over and over as my spiders crawl the site.

How would I cache the author profiles with Scrapy?

Comment: i think scrapy knows the previously visited link , so it should not crawl the already scraped page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add Duplicates filter like in the following example:

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

class DuplicatesPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.author_ids_seen = set()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if item['author_id'] in self.author_ids_seen:
            raise DropItem("Duplicate item found: %s" % item)
        else:
            self.ids_seen.add(item['author_id'])
            return item
```

and activate that DuplicatesPipeline in ITEM_PIPELINES list,

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = [
    'myproject.pipeline.DuplicatesPipeline',
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to implement the new caching policy. [see here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#std%3asetting-HTTPCACHE_POLICY)

Also look at the [HttpcacheMiddleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.httpcache.HttpCacheMiddleware)

I am still confused why its goes to visited page again . their docs says this for default policy

> This policy has no awareness of any HTTP Cache-Control directives.
>   Every request and its corresponding response are cached. When the same
>   request is seen again, the response is returned without transferring
>   anything from the Internet.